# Understanding the problem realm of text interactions

Tags: terminology, computational-linguistics

I am a complete linguisitic novice.

I have been exploring text analytic tools and I have become interested in how to extract interactions, mainly between humans in fictional text. I am trying to understand how to frame the problem and to find out what kind of things I should be looking up on Google or wherever.

I understand the field is probably hugely complicated depending on the level of interaction and what is defined as an interaction but if I could be given guidance as to the problem domain this falls into I would be very grateful

An example paragraph is:

> "I first met Dean not long after my wife and I split up. I had just gotten over a serious illness that I won't bother to talk about, except that it had something to do with the miserably weary split-up and my feeling that everything was dead. With the coming of Dean Moriarty began the part of my life you could call my life on the road. Before that I'd often dreamed of going West to see the country, always vaguely planning and never taking off. Dean is the perfect guy for the road because he actually was born on the road, when his parents were passing through Salt Lake City in 1926, in a jalopy, on their way to Los Angeles. First reports of him came to me through Chad King, who'd shown me a few letters from him written in a New Mexico reform school. I was tremendously interested in the letters because they so naively and sweetly asked Chad to teach him all about Nietzsche and all the wonderful intellectual things that Chad knew. At one point Carlo and I talked about the letters and wondered if we would ever meet the strange Dean Moriarty. This is all far back, when Dean was not the way he is today, when he was a young jailkid shrouded in mystery. Then news came that Dean was out of reform school and was coming to New York for the first time; also there was talk that he had just married a girl called Marylou."

I would like to extract the following relationships:

```
Narrator (I)- wife
Dean-parents
Dean-Chad King
I-Chad King
Chad-Nietzsche
Carlo-I
Carlo-Dean
Dean-Marylou
```

Comment: I do not quite follow, pardon.  Could you give an example paragraph or so and what you would like to be extracted from it?

Comment: So how can I automate the fact, in a sentence, that there is a relationship between two people eg "Fred gave Catherine the apple". Im not interested in the direction of the relationship

Comment: Still undefined, for example should it resolve pronouns?  Better a paragraph, with output as tuples or something.

Comment: A modern parser like https://demos.explosion.ai/displacy/ or https://indico.io will recognise named entities and persons.  But resolving third-person pronouns and other co-references is hard.